# java.util.NoSuchElementException in a java udp client?

Tags: java, networking, exception, udp, nosuchelementexception

I'm creating a simple UDP client and server in java. However,I keep getting a java.util.NoSuchElementException when I try to get the user to enter a second choice.

The first choice works great though. User enters number, packet gets sent to server, then back to the client. However when the loop comes back around to prompt the user for another choice, that's when the error occurs.

I've tried multiple different things, such as adding the scanner instantiation within the while loop, tried to clear the scan buffers by adding keyScan.nextLine() at the end of the while loop, changing nextInt to nextLine and parsing the line as an integer, all to no avail. I think it may be my lack of knowledge on how a scanner works when there's networking involved, as this is my first foray into java networking. Here's the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    //local constants
    final int CAP = 1;
    final int DATE = 2;
    final int FILE = 3;
    final int EXIT = 4;

    //local variables

    int choice;
    String sentence;
    boolean inputFlag = false;
    InetAddress IP;

    /**************************** BEGIN main *****************************/

    if(args.length == 1)
    {
        //convert arguments to bytes
        IP = getIP(args[0]);

        //IF it is a valid IP address
        if(IP != null)
        {
            //prompt user to make a choice
            while(inputFlag == false)
            {
                Scanner keyScan = new Scanner(System.in);
                //print the menu
                System.out.print(menu());
                try{
                    choice = keyScan.nextInt();

                    //capitalize
                    if(choice == CAP)
                    {
                        //get sentence from user and capitalize it
                        sentence = cap(IP);
                        System.out.println(sentence);
                    }
                    else
                        //set loop flag to true
                        inputFlag = true;

                }catch(InputMismatchException ime) {
                    //prompt user to enter correct input
                    System.out.println("This was not a valid input, use numbers"
                                     + " only!\n");
                    keyScan.next();
                }
                keyScan.nextLine();
            }//END WHILE
        }
        else
            System.out.println();
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("Usage: java UDPClient [IP address]");

}//END main
```

I have not implemented the date or file choices yet, just trying to get the gears working smoothly before I tackle those. Here's the stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
at UDPClient.main(UDPClient.java:164)
```

Comment: You should learn how to read the stackTrace and figure out which line the error occurred from :)

Comment: Post your StackTrace !!

Comment: @Ian Kindly, post the stack trace. Also, when you mention you have tried multiple things, you must elaborate "multiple" so that user answering your question must know what have you already tried.

Comment: I added some trouble shooting steps i've done to the top paragraphs and added the stack trace, first post, i apologize

Comment: error happens at the choice = keyScan.nextInt(); right after the try

Answer (score 0):

Working in the absence of a stacktrace, it could be as simple that you're allocating a new Scanner in System.in inside your while loop.  Thus System.in may have multiple scanners attached (absent of GC) and that may be illegal?

Alternately, the <CR> on input may have to be cleared from the Scanner before the next number can be read.

Answer (score 0):

if no more tokens are available in input then `NoSuchElementException` will be thrown.